# How to create a dark fade + text on image hover?

Tags: html, css, opacity

Having trouble trying to get a certain effect going on:

I have an image. I want to hover over it. It should turn a little black and have some text pop up.

[image: Here is an example]

example ^

What's the easiest/simplest setup to do this? Preferably only HTML and CSS

Note: The element needs a `background-image` being set in CSS.

```
    .thumbnail {
    background-image: url(potato.jpeg);
    height: 400px;
    width: 450px;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    height: 400px;
    width: 450px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: 0.8s;
}
```

\

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="thumbnail"> </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code, showing us what you've tried, to your question

Comment: Use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608381/caption-overlay-on-hover

Comment: check out :hover, transition for the background, and for the text, either a child div, or an :after:hover content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caption overlay on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608381/caption-overlay-on-hover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a seperate element for the overlay, in my example a child element. Only the hover status is visible, the regular status isn't, due to `opacity: 0`

```css
.thumbnail {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/450x400/fa0);
  height: 400px;
  width: 450px;
}
.overlay {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  height: 400px;
  width: 450px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
.thumbnail:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail"><div class="overlay"> </div> </div>
```

It becomes a bit more complex when text is involved which should have no opacity at all: In the following example the overlay element has a semi-transparent background-color and gets `opacity: 1` when the parent is hovered. That way the text has no opacity when hovered, but the background still has due to its own opacity setting of 0.5:

```css
.thumbnail {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/450x400/fa0);
  height: 400px;
  width: 450px;
}
.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 400px;
  width: 450px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.8s;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #fff;
}
.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail"><div class="overlay">SOME TEXT</div></div>
```

Comment: It's not only a second class, but a second element that contains another background and the text.

Comment: yes, it is in this case (there are other specific cases where I wouldn't do it that way) - I changed it accordingly in my second snippet

Comment: You can add more child elements and apply `position: absolute` to them (and `position: relative` to the parent element. Then you can position them using top, bottom, left and right parameters. `z-index` determines the stacking order among absolutely positioned elements that have the same parent element.